# How do you run multiple ruby files in conjunction in a shell script?

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a .sh file that looks like the following:

```
ruby one.rb
ruby two.rb
ruby three.rb
ruby four.rb
ruby five.rb
ruby six.rb
ruby seven.rb
ruby eight.rb
```

What this does is run the ruby files one by one. How would I go about launching the first four in conjunction and as soon as the first four are done grab the next set. Not sure how to approach this, any advice is appreciated. I want to avoid using rake for now and continue using shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried using `&` and `wait`?

```
ruby one.rb &
ruby two.rb &
ruby three.rb &
ruby four.rb &
wait
ruby five.rb &
ruby six.rb &
ruby seven.rb &
ruby eight.rb &
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: I wanted to give this answer using sub-shells, but was unsure of `wait`. +1 for good answer

Comment: woohoo that worked! learn something everyday.. *thumbs through subshells doc* Thanks!

Comment: @user2120790, you should click on the check mark to the left of this answer to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Create a text file which looks like:

```
 one.rb
 two.rb
 three.rb
```

...and so on. Call it "jobs" or whatever you want. Then, assuming you are running Ubuntu or a similar system:

```
 sudo apt-get install parallel
 parallel ruby < jobs
```

Information on the `parallel` command is available here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 0):

Do not avoid Rake. Learn it now and benefit ever after.

```
require 'rake'
run = -> sym { system "ruby #{sym}.rb" }
u, v = [:one, :two, :three, :four ], [:five, :six, :seven, :eight]
u.each { |sym| task sym do run.( sym ) end }
multitask midpoint: u
v.each { |sym| task sym => :midpoint do run.( sym ) end }
multitask( all: v ).invoke
```

Comment: No, I have thought about it, the gravity of this assertion warrants its existence as one of the possible answers.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Thanks, can't help with the downvotes, but that *did* stop it being deleted :)

Comment: does this really run them in parallel ? Doesn't `system` block until the command has finished?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: I have edited the answer, the join points should be `multitasks` rather than `tasks`. Good catch.